# Mixed Fractions/Mixed Numerals in Japanese

Tags: numbers

So I know how to read normal fractions (like 1/2) in Japanese but I was wondering how to read mixed fractions (such as 3 1/2). Would one just say 三と二分の一?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

"3 1/2" is generally read:

「[3]{さん}**か**[2分]{にぶん}の[1]{いち}」 by older people

and

「3**と**2分の1」 by younger people.

The 「と」 would clearly be the particle 「と」 meaning "and".

The 「か」, however, would probably be the counter 「箇{か}」.  (Where the 「か」 came from, we were never taught in school.)

Comment: か being 個 or 箇 is confirmed on [this site](http://fuji-san.txt-nifty.com/osusume/2016/07/post-4840.html).

Comment: Where would the counter be placed (e.g. if I have 3 cucumbers and a half)?